# Why are bots surfacing lots of old questions so that they show up in Active? Should they?

Tags: discussion, questions

In the Active questions list (which is the default view when going to the top level blender.stackexchange.com site) there appear to have been recently a lot of old questions, by which I mean they were asked from 1 to 5 years ago, sometimes answered, rarely even with an accepted answer (though I can't find one of those right now).

From what I can tell from the information I have available, a bot has edited something about the question and that's why it's in the active list again.  I cannot as far as I know see what's changed.

Here is an example: [one example of this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135096/how-to-make-a-window-brighter-without-changing-light-of-other-objects-in-the-roo)
and here is another: [another question link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60367/parent-shaking-when-hit-play-in-bge)

Why is this happening, and is it the intended behaviour?  If it's just bots improving old questions in some automatic and hard to tell way, should they even be put in Active?  There's a case that they're not actually active after all.

Comment: Yes, this is intended. See e.g.:
https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4674/why-does-community-make-old-questions-active-again
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412115/should-the-community-bot-stop-bumping-dead-questions

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/community-should-discriminate-more-when-bumping-unanswered-questions might be helpful as well to explain what Community ♦ is doing, and why.

Comment: I searched for this!  I used old and bot and various other search terms and I did not find it.  Sorry!